# how to Using different versions of jQuery and jQuery UI together

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

**I have worked the jQuery and jQuery UI with different version, I just using jQuery UI  drag the element in mobile view that normally works fine but they have conflict issue**

```
 _jQuery version ->3.6.0_ `<script src="../resources/vendors/jquery/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>`
_jQuery  UI version ->1.13.1_  `<script src="../resources/vendors/jquery/jquery_UI/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`
```

**they have conflict the jquery.min.js**

***error:***

```
 [Intervention] Ignored attempt to cancel a touchmove event with cancelable=false, for example, because scrolling is in progress and cannot be interrupted.

 [Intervention] Ignored attempt to cancel a touchstart event with cancelable=false, for example, because scrolling is in progress and cannot be interrupted.
 
 [Intervention] Ignored attempt to cancel a touchend event with cancelable=false, for example, because scrolling is in progress and cannot be interrupted.
```

*How to Using different versions of jQuery and jQuery UI together?*

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There should be no conflict with those two versions. Are you also using TouchPunch?

Comment: @Twisty thanks for your supporting! I've fix this error, during update touch-punch version

https://github.com/RWAP/jquery-ui-touch-punch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fix this error, during update touch-punch version 1.0.8

https://github.com/RWAP/jquery-ui-touch-punch

Comment: For future people who might have the same problem as you and stumble upon this question/answer, please be as detailed as possible regarding your resolution, such as specifying from which version you upgraded and to which version, etc.

Comment: sure sir @PLPeeters

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not idea, it is possible. Look into jQuery.noConflict() as described here: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: thank you! Could you please give send me a sample for this nonconflicted method using particular touch events